# How do I use Validation Sets on MultiOutputRegressor for XGBRegressor?

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, regression, xgboost

I'm using the following MultiOutputRegressor:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

#Define the estimator
estimator = XGBRegressor(
    objective = 'reg:squarederror'
    )

# Define the model
my_model = MultiOutputRegressor(estimator = estimator, n_jobs = -1).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I would like to use Validation Sets to evaluate my XGBRegressor's performance, however I believe that the `MultiOutputRegressor` does not support passing `eval_set` to the fit function.

How do I use Validation Sets in this case? Are there any workarounds to tweak an XGBRegressor to have multiple outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to edit the `fit` method of `MultiOutputRegressor` object like this:

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import _check_fit_params
from sklearn.base import is_classifier
from sklearn.utils.fixes import delayed
from joblib import Parallel
from sklearn.multioutput import _fit_estimator

class MyMultiOutputRegressor(MultiOutputRegressor):
    
    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, **fit_params):
        """ Fit the model to data.
        Fit a separate model for each output variable.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Data.
        y : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_outputs)
            Multi-output targets. An indicator matrix turns on multilabel
            estimation.
        sample_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None
            Sample weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted.
            Only supported if the underlying regressor supports sample
            weights.
        **fit_params : dict of string -> object
            Parameters passed to the ``estimator.fit`` method of each step.
            .. versionadded:: 0.23
        Returns
        -------
        self : object
        """

        if not hasattr(self.estimator, "fit"):
            raise ValueError("The base estimator should implement"
                             " a fit method")

        X, y = self._validate_data(X, y,
                                   force_all_finite=False,
                                   multi_output=True, accept_sparse=True)

        if is_classifier(self):
            check_classification_targets(y)

        if y.ndim == 1:
            raise ValueError("y must have at least two dimensions for "
                             "multi-output regression but has only one.")

        if (sample_weight is not None and
                not has_fit_parameter(self.estimator, 'sample_weight')):
            raise ValueError("Underlying estimator does not support"
                             " sample weights.")

        fit_params_validated = _check_fit_params(X, fit_params)
        [(X_test, Y_test)] = fit_params_validated.pop('eval_set')
        self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(_fit_estimator)(
                self.estimator, X, y[:, i], sample_weight,
                **fit_params_validated, eval_set=[(X_test, Y_test[:, i])])
            for i in range(y.shape[1]))
        return self
```

and than pass the `eval_set` to the `fit` method:

```
fit_params = dict(
        eval_set=[(X_test, Y_test)], 
        early_stopping_rounds=10
        )
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, **fit_params)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! It works for me. Just one typo in this line, [(X_test, Y_test)] = fit_params_validated.pop('eval_set'), which should be like this: [X_test, Y_test] = fit_params_validated.pop('eval_set'). i.e. using [X_test, Y_test] or (X_test, Y_test) to extract train and test data for validation set.

Answer (score 0):

By making several minor edits/changes, @itamar-kanter's solution works for me. The comments are a bit long, so it's better written as an answer rather than comment(s).

Noticed that @itamar-kanter's solution may get inspiration from fit() function for [darts.utils.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/_modules/darts/utils/multioutput.html):

1. A typo in this line, [(X_test, Y_test)] = fit_params_validated.pop('eval_set'), which should be like this:

   ```
    [X_test, Y_test] = fit_params_validated.pop('eval_set')
   ```

   i.e. using [X_test, Y_test] or (X_test, Y_test) to extract train and test data for validation set.

   Alternatively, one can use the same syntax as fix() in  [darts.utils.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/_modules/darts/utils/multioutput.html):

   ```
    eval_set = fit_params_validated.pop("eval_set")

    self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(_fit_estimator)(
                self.estimator,
                X,
                y[:, i],
                sample_weight,
                # eval set may be a list (for XGBRegressor), in which case we have to keep it as a list
                eval_set=[(eval_set[0][0], eval_set[0][1][:, i])]
                if isinstance(eval_set, list)
                else (eval_set[0], eval_set[1][:, i]),
                **fit_params_validated
            )
            for i in range(y.shape[1])
   ```
2. The right way to import Pallel and delayed function should be the same as that from [darts.utils.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/_modules/darts/utils/multioutput.html):

   ```
    try:
         # delayed was moved from sklearn.utils.fixes to sklearn.utils.parallel in v1.3
         from sklearn.utils.parallel import Parallel, delayed
    except ImportError:
         from joblib import Parallel
         from sklearn.utils.fixes import delayed
   ```

   Here, using the try ... except ... to import Pallel and delayed can avoid the unnecessary UserWarning from parallel.py: "*sklearn.utils.parallel.delayed should be used with sklearn.utils.parallel.Parallel to make it possible to propagate the scikit-learn configuration of the current thread to the joblib workers*".

   Meanwhile, using sklearn's inner functions 'from sklearn.utils.parallel import Parallel, delayed', rather than 'from joblib import Parallel, delayed', can make ML training faster. I guess sklearn's inner  implementation has some unique features which works better with parallelising sklearn ML models?
3. Finally, "from sklearn.utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets" is missing in the import part in @itamar-kanter's code?